# how to show top navigation bar after selecting the list?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, top-link-bar, branding

I am using SharePoint 2010. When I select List then the site navigation menu is lost i need that menu remain same after selecting the list and also need the list Tool bar as it is. I want to do this for all list and sub-sites also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the steps for solution:

1) Open your main site in SharePoint Designer and copy **v4.master** for Backup

2) Open **v4.master** Master page of your site

3) find the `<div id="s4-topheader2" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg">` which inside the `<div id="s4-titlerow" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle">` and put it below and outside of it and above the `<div id="s4-statusbarcontainer"> <div id="pageStatusBar" class="s4-status-s1"></div></div>`

4)Check for **Master Page** link in Look and Feel menu if it is already there then no need to follow step 5 and 6 directly go to step 7

5) now go Site Settings ->   Site Collection Administration and open Site Collection Features find feature **SharePoint server Publishing Infrastructure** and activate this

[image]

[image]

6) Again go to Site Settings  -> Site Actions and click on **Manage site features** then activate  **SharePoint Server Publishing**  this will enable Master Page in Look and fill menu

[image]

[image]

7) go to Look and Feel -> Master page -> Check the Check-box  "Reset all sub-sites to inherit this site master page setting" in both Site Master Page and System Master Page then click OK.

[image]

[image]

**After following the step you got the desire output ::**

[image]